# Accessing a Windows server via Console makes RDP sessions mouse cursor jump around?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, remote-desktop

I have a newly re-created Virtual 2008 R2 Remote Desktop Server with 15 users (via ESXi). When I'm not logged in via a console session, everybody's sessions work perfectly. However, as soon as I log in with a console session via ESXi's VMRC everybody's mouse suddenly start jumping around tracking my mouse.

I've never heard of this problem,and the normal research channels are turning up nothing (except for when Citrix is involved, but we arn't using Citrix at all).

The server has 8 cores and 24Gig of ram on a Gig network, and all users are in local network.